# Koa is being executed twice per request?

Tags: node.js, koa2

Is there any reason why Koa is being executed **twice** per request?

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

const index = async(ctx, next) => {
  console.log('Hello world!')
  await next()
  ctx.body = 'Hello world!'
}

app.use(index);

app.listen(3000)
```

On my terminal, I get:

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Guess: `/favicon.ico`

Comment: @robertklep how do i fix that?

Comment: Add a handler for `/favicon.ico`. Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416784

Comment: I wanna help you but my node doesn't download koa module for some reason

Comment: @robertklep it seems fixed with favicon.ico. but why does it do that without a favicon.ico?

Comment: Because your `index` handler matches _any_ request. And browsers typically try to retrieve `/favicon.ico` for a page, so you'll get two requests: one for the page, and one to see if there's a favicon for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two reasons why this could happen:

**First** is - as already mentioned in the comments that browsers also fire a request for favicon.ico
**Second**: some browsers do a prefentching, so before you even hit the return key, they prefetch the url when entering.

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

const index = async(ctx, next) => {
  console.log('URL --> ' + ctx.request.url); // This logs out the requested route
  console.log('Hello world!')
  await next()
  ctx.body = 'Hello world!'
}

app.use(index);

app.listen(3000)
```

I added one line to your code so that you can see which routes your browser asks for. This might help identify the reason for your problem.

Comment: Correct: most of the time it's just the browser asking for `/favicon.ico` as @robertklep has pointed out. even when specifying the type to be `application/json` the browser still does that.