# How to remove the default CRA react favicon?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I already remove the link in the head tag and still the favicon gets rendered, is there anyway this can be remove or change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/5647260 - Maybe this'll help?

Answer (score 92):

Your favicon is in project_root > public > favicon.ico.

```
|
`--- public
     |
     `--- favicon.ico
```

Removing it is hard as browser generally uses a cached favicon if it doesn't find anything.

I'd urge you to change it. Just replace the `favicon.ico` file with an image of your choice. You can even rename a png to `favicon.ico` and use it. Make sure you do a hard refresh. You have to burst cache to see that change.

If you want to go all in on this, generate a favicon using https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Comment: Can you be more specific on what a "hard refresh" is?

Comment: It's just refreshing the page with clearing cache. You can do it with ctrl-f5 in pc or cmd-shift-R in mac https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.W3ZP15MzbrQ

Comment: How to burst cache?

Comment: @MadHatter, do a [hard refresh](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/)

Comment: In my case I tried all the above but still it still wasn't working, so for me the hard refresh was to kill the terminal and start again and it worked.

Comment: Clearing cache is not removing it! @sudo

Comment: The editor or server doesn't have much to do with it. The icon is cached in the browser

Comment: @rodrigocfd if you have dev tools open you can right click the refresh button and you will see 3 options, normal reload, hard reload, and empty cache and hard reload, which will delete your cached images ;)

Answer (score 16):

Try this:-

Change 
 `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />` to

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/a.png" /> which should be not present by the way or try deleting the favicon
```

Comment: This alone won't work alongside this you have to remove your favicon.ico file as well

Answer (score 11):

You have to do all the above (or below), but you also need to clear your browsing history.

Comment: I was scratching my head for a while there... very good point.

Answer (score 7):

Go to directory of your project → public → open `manifest.json`:

```
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change it from the public directory with your own favicon and but you'll see while developemnt but when you run

```
npm run build
```

you won't see it in the index.html link tag 
you'll only see it on the development .

Answer (score 5):

just simply rename your image to favicon.ico and replace the actual favicon.ico image in public-folder by your renamed-image. and then just refresh you page..

Comment: this was simple and easy to do..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may have to generate the flavicon.  After you decide on an image that you want to use for the flavicon, this site will help you generate the .ico file.  You may have to edit the HTML to include the correct resizing properties.

https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Answer (score 4):

Just Navigate to public Folder in your react project and then remove the file named favicon.ico. Then after you should replace that file with your favorite icon or any png image by renaming it as favicon.ico like the one you had before. then refresh your page.

Answer (score 1):

get your icon and replace it with ~your_director~/public/favicon.ico

then refresh site.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your project_folder/public/favicon.io with your icon. You can just rename your .png or .jpeg file to favicon.io, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to index.html file. After that remove the default href value () from it and simply replace your icon source here.

Answer (score 0):

download icon file and place it in public folder
rename it favicon
after renaming open in any editor and open that file and then refresh

Answer (score 0):

Fast changes without deleting Browser cache or history :
Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the favicon.ico , move any image in public folder and rename in favicon.ico ....worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your favicon and images is in your 'public' directory.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

Then clear cache and the favicon should be updated.