# React Icon showing up even after removing it

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I have removed the default React icon from the `index.html` file in create-react-app, but, it is still showing up.

Here is the code of `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full bg-gray-50">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>ResumeBuilder</title>
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Icon showing in tab title]

**Folder structure** of public of create-react-app:

[image: folder structure]

**How can I remove it?**

Comment: I think restarting server and resetting cache will help

Comment: There are multiple things to try out until you get the correct outcome. Please try the answers mentioned in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970778/how-to-remove-the-default-cra-react-favicon

Answer (score 0):

A simple shortcut could help:
Ctrl+F5 will do a force cache purge for your page.

Comment: It does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace reactjs Icon with your website logo Icon

you can easily generate online a favicon there are many websites available like this - https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Open the above site select your site logo and generate a favicon then download the zip file and extract the zip file and copy the logo icon from the generated folder and replace it with react js default icon.

Comment: Is there any option if I want to remove it and not replace it?

Comment: You should to manually from public folder