# How to fix this error? ( http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found))

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, passport.js

How ti fix this?

> http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

The server has this error message:

> Not Found 404 Error: Not Found
>       at D:\nodetour\app.js:82:13
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
>       at next (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
>       at Function.handle (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\nodetour\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at D:\nodetour\app.js:74:3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent favicon.ico requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests)

Comment: You can fix it by serving a favicon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this module to serve favicon.ico for express app

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon

Comment: don't forget to plus