# How to prevent `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1` from being called after GET request

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python Flask web app. Whenever I visit any of the endpoints via my chrome browser, a `GET` request is invoked to retrieve the webpage (this is expected), but then, it appears Chrome sends a follow-up `GET` request for a `favicon.ico` to the same endpoint Chrome just hit.

For example, my app exoses the following endpoint at route `/` (shown below):

```py
# General Landing Page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title="Home")
```

When I hit this endpoint with my Google Chrome, the `index.html` page is returned just fine. But my log messages show the following:

```sh
 env FLASK_APP=app/routes.py flask run --port 5001
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2020 23:15:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2020-02-18 23:15:23,647] ERROR in app: Exception on /favicon.ico [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

As you can see, the `/` endpoint is hit and returns a status code of `200 OK`, but then a subsequent call to `favicon.ico` errors out.  How does one handle this?

Answer (score 5):

The `favicon.ico` is the default file name for an icon used to display on the browser tabs or bookmarks.

If you want to put an icon, you can create one with the name `favicon.ico` and place it in the `static` directory of the application. And put a link tag in your html file.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
```

Follow this [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/favicon/) for more info from flask docs.

And follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/3342969) if you are looking for skipping this `GET` request